# Issues in writing to a list from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm having trouble figuring what I have done wrong in this code.  It appears to be stuck in a infinite loop and I have to kill the process.  In the end this code will be used to convert files to Geojson format, however before I start writing to Geojson I want to make sure I can open and append to the dictionary.

What I have found is that after I try and append the csv file to a list and print out the list (line 23, note this print line is only there to help me trouble shoot the problem), there is only 1 row of data (there should be a lot more than that, maybe 20-30 rows of varying column lengths. Yes I have checked the input file.)  I have also tried running the csv input on another programme and there is no issues with it, so I suspect the problem is something in the code I have written.

Thanks for any help.

```
import csv

def main():
    try:
        strFOLDER = ( r'/Users/Smithy/Documents/Pycharm/' + '/')
        strFILE = raw_input("Enter the name of file " )
        my_file  = strFOLDER + strFILE
    except IOError:
        print 'Cannot read/locate file error'

    try:
        fp = open(my_file, 'rU')
        my_data = csv.reader(fp)
    except IOError:
        print 'Cannot read/locate file error'

    my_list = []
    my_dictionary = {}

    for row in my_data:
        my_list.append(row)
        print my_list
        list_len = len(my_list)
        num_count = 0
        while num_count < list_len:
            if (num_count < (list_len-2)):
                my_dictionary['name'] = [1]
                my_dictionary['location'] = ([num_count+2], [num_count+3])
                my_list.append(my_dictionary)
                num_count+=2

main()
```

Comment: Try moving numcount += 2 outside of the if statement.

Comment: I also assume that mydictionary = {} should be placed inside of the for loop to ensure it is overwritten for each row

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop, you don't do anything if (num_count > (list_len-2)), so this loop doesn't end, and only the first row is displayed.

More precisely, when you append the first row to `my_list`, the length of this one is 1. The if clause becomes `if (num_count < (1 - 2))`, which obviously doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck in the `while` loop.

Your problem is that `num_count+=2` never happens unless `num_count < (list_len-2)` happens to be true. `list_len` is equal to `1` the first time you append to it and thus `num_count` is never incremented.